# PySimpleGUI breaks pynput. How do I combine them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput, pysimplegui

As soon as I've pressed the alt+ctrl+t shortcut once and closed the pop-up window, pynput will react to any double click of the shortcut keys. For example, if I press "t" twice, it will open the window again (even though alt+ctrl are not pressed).
Is there a way to combine pynput's global hotkeys with PySimpleGUI?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pynput import keyboard

def f_test():
    layout = [[sg.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")], [sg.Button("OK")]]
    window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "OK" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<alt>+<ctrl>+t': f_test}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with different threads for `PySimpleGUI` and `pynput`.

```py
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pynput import keyboard

def f(key):
    window.write_event_value(key, None)

def func():
    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
            '<alt>+<ctrl>+t': lambda key='Hotkey1':f(key),
            '<alt>+<ctrl>+q': lambda key='Hotkey2':f(key)}) as h:
        h.join()

def f_test():
    layout = [[sg.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")], [sg.Button("OK")]]
    window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "OK" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()

layout = [[sg.Text("")]]
window = sg.Window("Main Script", layout, finalize=True)
window.hide()
threading.Thread(target=func, daemon=True).start()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event)
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Hotkey2'):
        break
    elif event == 'Hotkey1':
        f_test()

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for me.
If you have time to answer one more question: how come I need two threads of pysimplegui? 
When I read about threading, I assumed I could start one thread of PySimpleGUI and another thread with pynput and they would run independently but that didn't work.

Comment: Although Tkinter is technically thread-safe (assuming Tk is built with --enable-threads), practically speaking there are still problems when used in multithreaded Python applications. The problems stem from the fact that the PySimpleGUI/tkinter attempts to gain control of the main thread via a polling technique when processing calls from other threads. Most of time, PySimpleGUI/tkinter will be in main thread.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.